# Grouping by two values

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have this table: (id, carId, gasStationId, liters, totalPrice). I would like to create query for sum total costs in each gas stations by car. I know how to sum total costs by gas station, but I don't know how to group by car.
Here is my query:

```
select sum(totalPrice) as totalCosts
     , count(*) as countPurchases
     , g.name
     , p.carId 
  from purchase as p
  join gas_station as g  
    on g.id = p.id
 group 
    by gasStationId
```

I would like get this result:

```
┌─────────────┬──────┬──────┐
│ GasStation1 │ Car1 │ 1000 │
├─────────────┼──────┼──────┤
│ GasStation1 │ Car2 │ 1500 │
│ GasStation2 │ Car2 │  500 │
│ GasStation2 │ Car1 │  700 │
└─────────────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `group by gasStationId, carId` or are you wanting to join another table you're not showing?

Comment: You can group by more than 1 field.

Comment: Side note: Why do you have `gasStationId` in your grouping? It looks like it should've been `g.id`. But I following your query in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same thing, just add `p.carId` to the grouping separated by a comma:

```
GROUP BY gasStationId, p.carId
```

So for the results in your question, you can do:

```
SELECT g.name, p.carId, SUM(totalPrice) AS totalCosts
FROM purchase AS p
JOIN gas_station AS g ON g.id = p.id
GROUP BY gasStationId, p.carId
```

Answer (score 0):

A good idea is to use window functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

something like:

```
SELECT
     gasStationId,
     SUM(totalPrice) OVER(PARTITION BY carId) AS price_by_car
   FROM purchase p
   JOIN gasStations g
   ON g.id=p.gassStationId;
```

Comment: Where did you get `profit` from? And in the output example, the OP has one total, not two.

Comment: I'll fix it. Just added the total per station for completeness.